# How to prove $n^4 = \mathcal{O}(2^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm new to asymptotic notations and right now I'm trying to prove that $n^4 = \mathcal{O}(2^n)$. 
In my current solution (written below) I used L'Hôpital's rule repeatedly, proving that the limit of $n^4/2^n$ goes to zero. Is this correct?
Additionally I'm wondering whehter there is a simpler solution to this problem. 
I tried induction but didn't get far. If you see an easier solution I would gladly appreciate any hints.

Thanks for any answers.

$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4}{2^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4*n^3}{2^n * ln(2)} = ..... = 0$

Comment: There is faster solution: $n=2^{\log_2 n}$

Comment: Yes, it is correct. rus9384's suggested solutions is a bit slicker though.

Comment: @Imago, he still would need to prove $1/2^{\lim_{n\to\infty}n-4\log_2 n}\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned trying induction, to no avail. However, induction does work. Let's prove by induction that for all $n \geq 6$, $$n^4 \leq \frac{81}{4} 2^n.$$
This is true for $n = 6$ (both sides are equal to 1296). Suppose that it holds for some $n \geq 6$. Then
$$
(n+1)^4 = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^4 n^4 = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^4 n^4 \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^4 n^4.
$$
You can calculate that $(7/6)^4 < 2$ (equivalently, $2401 = 7^4 < 2 \cdot 6^4 = 2592$). Therefore, using the induction hypothesis,
$$
(n+1)^4 < 2n^4 \leq 2 \frac{81}{4} 2^n = \frac{81}{4} 2^{n+1}.
$$
Thus the inequality holds for $n+1$ as well, completing the proof by induction.